# Firefox unset my master password

Tags: firefox, passwords, firefox-sync

For some time I have been using Firefox Sync across multiple computers, keeping the data encrypted with a master password.

But yesterday in my Security tab, I saw that my password had somehow been removed - the "use a master password" option was unchecked, and I could view all my stored passwords without having to enter it!

What does this mean?  Has an unscrupulous addon unencrypted my database?  Should I consider changing all my stored passwords?

Comment: It means your password database likely for awhile now has not been encrypted.

Comment: I can't be sure exactly, but I don't think it would take me long to notice not having to type it.  It is almost certainly less than a week ago, since that's when I last logged in to Ubuntu, and the password was still set in Firefox there.

Answer (score 0):

Could be an addon, but I think its more plausible that some sort of modification in your home folder also somehow affected the profiles in .mozilla/firefox. Or maybe another program made changes there on purpose, or the package management system used for installing and updating Firefox etc. somehow screw it up.

If the system itself is not compromised, and has not been accessed by any other person (stolen laptop, siblings, significant other ;-), I don't think that changing your passwords is necessary.

Changing some or even all of your passwords on a regular basis is not a bad habit, though. ;-)